# fql - getting permissions for fields which are returning null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

my question is very novice, but since I don't find an answer I have decided to ask, so it is simple: I'm trying to get some fields but if I use for example:

```
SELECT uid,name, birthday_date, hometown_location 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I'm getting null in some fields ()

```
"birthday_date": null, 
      "hometown_location": null
```

I've read about permission(I need friends_birthday
friends_hometown) in this case, what do I need to do to achieve this permissions? I have read the facebook documentation but It's not understable. Thanks

Comment: Some users in Facebook haven't set their birthday or hometown locations, and some users explicitly block apps from receiving such information. In any case, your app will need to be able to handle null values.

Comment: but the users who are not blocked the apps and have that info available, what is the way to get their info? the problem is that I get null in all contacts.

Comment: Do you use the application access token ? Or an application user access token ? If I know that, I can help you further